# Is there a BigQuery solution to find average time between events?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have a request to deliver aggregate GA data and I can't quite wrap my head around, there are three events that do not immediately following one another:

Event A -> Event B -> Event C

The question are:

1. What is the total volume of sessions where Event B is eventually triggered after Event A in the same session? What is the success rate i.e:

> (Sessions where Event B follows Event A) / Sessions where Event A is triggered

2. What is the average time it takes between triggering Event A and event B, in a given time period? I.e.:

> (Timestamp B - Timestamp A) / # of Sessions = **Y**

3. What is the volume and average number of times (per day) that Event C is triggered within 5 minutes of **Y**? I.e.

> Count of Sessions where (Timestamp C <= **Y** + 5) / # of Days

Any help here would be great, thanks so much for your time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It can be easily done. I have worked on this type of problem before. Please include your example inputs and outputs and I can help you with the query.